# waitForSelector("...", function success()/function fail() purpose?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, casperjs

Just starting out on casperJs and noticed the option of

```
waitForSelector("....", function success() {

},
function fail() {

});
```

My question is, what is the difference of this and using an if/else statement for successful code and errors? Are there benefits of one over the other? I've searched online, and on here, and haven't been able to find anything definitive.

Comment: You mean, the difference to a single callback function that uses an `if` statement with some condition on the arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
waitForSelector(String selector, Function then, Function onTimeout, Number timeout)
```

is an asynchronous step function, which is why it doesn't return as soon as the selector is found, but it immediately returns the `casper` object, because CasperJS supports a fluent API. You simply cannot use `if-else` to check for success or failure of the wait.

The call to `waitForSelector()` schedules a waiting step. This scheduled step can end in one of three ways:

- selector is found: the `then` function is executed as a separate step if it's passed. Otherwise, the next scheduled step is executed.
- selector is not found during the waiting time (timeout): if an `onTimeout` function was passed, then this function is executed as a separate step which catches the onTimeout error. If it wasn't passed and there is no global onTimeout handler, then a `CasperError` is thrown which exits the script.
- There was some other error thrown which is not caught by `then` or `onTimeout` and the script exits.

So, if you name those functions that you pass in `success` and `fail`, you should know that this naming is only correct with regard to the timeout functionality.

Comment: Very good explanation of the <code>waitForSelector</code> function. To dive a little deeper into my question, what's the preferred method of checking errors?
<code> casper.then(function() {
       if(something)
             test.pass("Pass");
       else
             test.fail("Fail");
}); </code>
Or the <code>waitForSelector</code> function with <code>success</code> and <code>fail</code> passed in?

Comment: They are not interchangeable. If you have synchronous code, then you can use `if`. If you need to wait for a selector (asynchronous), then you need to use `waitForSelector()`. You don't need to pass in any callbacks, because CasperJS will automatically exit the script if the selector was not found.

Answer (score 0):

`waitForSelector` is an async function and it doesn't have an immediate value to return. That's why it is returned in callback functions. `waitForSelector` can throw an exception somewhere down the chain or could fail unexpectedly and throw an exception. In that case, error call back function `fail()` would be called, and thats where you can gracefully handle the error. If/else is synchronous behavior working on a deterministic value.

Comment: `fail` doesn't handle arbitrary JavaScript errors. It *only* handles the timeout. Also, `waitForSelector()` does return something. It's the `casper` object in order to chain further steps.